# Swift - Enum Binding initialized not change after update it in nested view

Tags: swiftui, binding

as the title suggests, the binding of an enum that I initialized in the parent view does not update when it is updated in the child view (to be honest grandchild). Oddly enough, if I then update the binding with the same value I initialized it with, it magically starts updating correctly.

Am I doing something wrong with the binding?

CONTENT VIEW:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    //...
    @State var selectedTransactionType: TransactionType = .income
    
    //...
    
    var body: some View {
        //....
                // MARK: Navigation Bar
                NavBarView(selectedTab: $selectedTab, showingPopover: $showingPopover, chosenOption: $selectedTransactionType, navBarWidth: navBarWidth)
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showingPopover){
                EditTransactionView(selectedTrType: selectedTransactionType)
            }

//...
```

NavBarView:

```
struct NavBarView: View {
    @Binding var selectedTab: Tabs
    @Binding var showingPopover: Bool
    @Binding var chosenOption: TransactionType
    
    let navBarWidth: CGFloat
    
    @State var showAddingOptions: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
      //...

            if showAddingOptions {
                AddingOptions(radius: navBarWidth/8.5, showingPopover: $showingPopover, showAddingOptions: $showAddingOptions, chosenOption: $chosenOption)
                    .offset(y: -offsetOptions)
            }

//...

// MARK: AddingOptions
struct AddingOptions: View {
    let radius: CGFloat
    @Binding var showingPopover: Bool
    @Binding var showAddingOptions: Bool
    @Binding var chosenOption: TransactionType

    var body: some View {

//...

            Button {
                showingPopover = true
                showAddingOptions = false
                chosenOption = TransactionType.income
            } label: {

//...
```

Do you have any tips to better understand the flow using the debugger?
Trying to take the button one step at a time, you start jumping to other threads and you no longer understand why the value is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue managing the sheet view presentation directly with the parameter that I need to share.

```
        //....
            NavBarView(selectedTab: $selectedTab, chosenOption: $selectedTrType, navBarWidth: navBarWidth)
        }
        .sheet(item: $selectedTrType){ trType in
            NavigationStack {
                EditTransactionView(selectedTrType: selectedTransactionType)
            }
        }
```

I did this in order to force the sheet view to open only when the value is correctly changed.